# Issue about multiple grouping. How to get a single row from a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

This is a table with my data:

```
-----------------------------
|   date   |  value  |  id  |
|03/05/18  |5        | 1    |
|03/05/18  |3        | 2    |
|03/05/18  |5        | 3    |
|03/05/18  |6        | 4    |
|03/05/18  |9        | 5    |
|08/03/19  |5        | 6    |
|08/03/19  |3        | 7    |
|08/03/19  |1        | 8    |
|08/03/19  |6        | 9    |
|01/06/20  |7        | 10   |
|01/06/20  |0        | 11   |
|01/06/20  |2        | 12   |
-----------------------------
```

I need to find the maximum **value** in each **date** and output it with corresponding **id**.
Example:

```
-----------------------------
|   date   |  value  |  id  |
|03/05/18  |9        | 5    |
|08/03/19  |6        | 9    |
|01/06/20  |7        | 10   |
-----------------------------
```

Now I know how output the maximum **value** in each **date** but *without* corresponding **id**.
Example:

```
----------------------
|   date   |  value  |
|03/05/18  |9        |
|08/03/19  |6        |
|01/06/20  |7        |
----------------------
```

Software I use is MS SQL Server 2012.

My code:

```
    SELECT 
    date,
    MIN(value)
    
    FROM 
    my_table
    
    GROUP BY date
```

I've tried the SQL Server function "**FIRST_VALUE**" but it didn't help.

ALSO I tried to create a comparing condition in a subquery and run into some problems with specifying variables (alias) outside and inside my subquery.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Calculate `row_number() over (partition by date order by value desc) as rn` in a CTE and then filter for `rn = 1`

Comment: @dnoeth, thanks! I did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.value = (select max(t1.value) from mytable t1 where t1.date = t.date)
```

This would allow top ties, if any. Another option is to use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by date order by value desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

If you want to break ties, you can use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` - but to get a stable result, you would need a second column in the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I tried both methods but I get strange results.

My table wasn't filtered out. In the **value** field, I only have a constant for all records

Comment: What is the data type for your field named 'value'?